# UrlRewriterFilter rule not working

Tags: java, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I use `Struts` for my web application.

For rewriting URLs I use [UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/).

This is my `urlrewrite.xml` code:

```
<urlrewrite>
<rule>
    <from>^/job/([0-9]+)$</from>
    <to>/job.do?selAction=detail&amp;idx=$1</to>
</rule>
<rule>
    <from>^/jobs</from>
    <to>/job.do</to>
</rule>
<rule>
    <from>^/main</from>
    <to>/main.do</to>
</rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

First and second URI work well. But third one (`^/main`) is not working. 
When I change third URI from `^/main` to `^/main/`, it works but I don't know how (I guess it is related with URI depth). What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `$` at the end of your 2nd and 3rd `<from>` tags, as suggested in the [manual](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/2.6/):

```
<rule>
    <from>^/jobs$</from>
    <to>/job.do</to>
</rule>
<rule>
    <from>^/main$</from>
    <to>/main.do</to>
</rule>
```